# How do I pass an NSItemProvider object into a dictionary in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am hoping this is a very very nooby/easy Obj C question:

I am trying to pass this `NSItemProvider` as an object into my `NSDictionary` so that I can pass it in to my react native `rootView` as `initialProps` but it just gets passed as Null all the time.. what am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)loadView {
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
  NSExtensionItem *item = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
  NSItemProvider *itemProvider = item.attachments.firstObject;
  NSDictionary *initialProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[[NSNumber numberWithBool: TRUE], itemProvider] forKeys:@[@"isActionExtension",@"key2"]];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"ActionExtensionExample4"
                                               initialProperties:initialProps
                                                   launchOptions:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  self.view = rootView;
  actionViewController = self;
}
```

please help! thank you! I know this must be a trivial thing for people who actually know Obj C!

Comment: Are you sure that `itemProvider` is not nil? What happens if you log it, and also log `initialProps` immediately after you create it?

Comment: Also, in Objective-C, the correct Boolean constants to use are `YES` and `NO`, not `TRUE`. Additionally, you can box an NSNumber using the `@()` syntax, so just `@(YES)` is a lot more concise than `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`.

Comment: thank you Charles, I'm afraid i just copy/pasted that Boolean code from here (https://www.promptworks.com/blog/building-ios-app-extensions-with-react-native) which is why I was treating it so gingerly. its what happens when javascript guys try to muck around with obj C :( i will try the logging, but I would be very surprised if itemProvider is nil because the whole point of a share extension is to share data... (sorry I should have made it more explicit that this is code for an ios Share Extension).

Comment: Actually I'm not sure why I focused on just the `NSNumber`. Simplify the whole dictionary to just `@{ @"isActionExtension" : @(YES), @"key2" : itemProvider }`. The simpler it is, the less likely for it to get messed up by a typo.